# MySQLdump is executing, but not actually working

Tags: mysql, database, backup, mysql-backup

I'm trying to back up and restore a MySQL database using mysqldump. With my commands I am making a back up file and then restoring that file, but where I'm restoring the database shows no change.

*This creates the backup folder in the same directory as the mysqldump.exe file:*

In the windows cmd: `mysqldump -u root -pxxxxxx test2 > test2backup.sql`

Restoring with that file: `mysqldump -u root -pxxxxxx test < test2backup.sql`

`test` is an empty database. `test2` is a database with tables and data. Running this should fill `test` with `test2`'s data using the `test2backup.sql` file, should it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For importing you do not need `mysqldump` rather

```
mysql -u root -pxxxxxx test < test2backup.sql
```